# Booting from USB on Acer V5-571G

Tags: boot, windows-10, acer

I have an Acer V5-571G with Windows 10 installed on it, I am trying to run Ubuntu from USB (Booting from USB) after I changed the boot setting the PC got slower then proceed to Windows. It seems that Acer blocks the user from Booting from USB ... so, can you help me to do it?
Thanks ...

Comment: Older thread with Acer V5: Acer V5-571P-6815 secure boot off worked Shows Diskpart
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081311
Make sure you have newest UEFI from Acer. Acer Very latest UEFI/BIOS works, downgrade not required:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2298380&p=13419141#post13419141
Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: I did it, changed boot setting to legancy but now I can't turn back to windows!  I got "boot error" whenever I try to boot from hard disk.  Please help ..

Comment: Sorry,  legacy ...

Comment: Windows is probably UEFI, better to install in UEFI mode. Boot-Repair can in advanced options do a full uninstall/reinstall of grub2 which can convert to UEFI boot. First do this, to confirm configuration: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 2):

I just got over a similar problem with my ACER laptop, maybe the trick can help!

Problem : After disabling fast boot and secure boot, my laptop would not recognize the USB stick.

Solution I came up with :

1. **remove** the USB stick
2. boot and enter BIOS
3. reset default settings & reboot
4. re-enter BIOS
5. disable "secure boot" and enable the F12 function (which allows you to select the boot device on start up)
6. **insert** the USB stick
7. save settings and reboot
8. mash F12 like crazy
9. select USB to boot
10. Make a happy dance of joy

I sure hope this can help someone, since I spent *a lot* of time searching solutions to this problem, to no avail!

Answer (score 0):

I detailed the solution for installing Ubuntu on an Acer Aspire series here: [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536)

Short answer:

1. disable secureboot
2. install from rufus created USB
3. add shimx64.EFI to trusted UEFI
4. enable secure boot.