# How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

Following the guide for installing Ubuntu on a Windows 10 Home Edition system did not work with an Acer Aspire V3-575T. After installation usb is removed and the system is restarted, it gives a no boot media error.  I believe the solution will apply to other models with Windows 10 Home / secureboot and UEFI.

Comment: I was unclear, I was refering to  https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I have finally managed to install ubuntu on an Acer computer and wrote the exact instructions here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151313/instructions-on-how-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-tc-885-series-could-work-w

Answer (score 13):

Detailed steps I used to successfully install:

Create a boot USB with the Ubuntu image file using Rufus as detailed here:
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Insert USB in the forward left hand side USB connector 
(the USB connector on the right side of the computer will not work)

Reboot the computer and access the BIOS with F2:

- Use arrow keys to navigate to BOOT screen
- Select Secure Boot and change value to disable
- On the Boot priority order move USB-HDD to the top
- F10 to save and exit

Proceed with the installation type of choice.

After the installation has completed, and is prompting you to restart:

- Remove the USB drive
- (on reboot) Access the BIOS again  with F2
- On the BIOS page Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing
- Navigate to: HDD0 > EFI > 'ubuntu' and select SHIMX64.EFI
  (Enter shimx64 as name)
- Navigate to the BOOT tab:
- Select Secure boot, change value to Enabled
- F10 to save and exit

I followed these exact steps, installed without errors, and am using Ubuntu on
my Acer V3 now.

Comment: I've followed the exactly above steps but its get stuck after entering password at login. do you have any idea ?

Comment: Had to add grubx64.efi to the top of the list and disable secure boot, otherwise it kept restarting.

Answer (score 1):

For other UEFI options,you might want to try installing Ubuntu with Secure boot enabled. If boot fails then disable it. You should also disable fast boot (if available) and enable USB boot as well. If everything else fails then you should install Ubuntu in Legacy mode. Afterwards, use Boot-Repair tool to adjust Grub2 (it is an automated process). Then you can boot both OS from the same UEFI mode. (Boot, to change the boot device order)

As for the installation of Ubuntu itself, if you are new to this procedure, take my advice and you should see some explanatory video, for it is reported that some people had some issues when it comes to selecting the installation type. Of course, if you want Windows alongside Ubuntu, you should choose the "Something else" option, it's the last one.

Then select the partition for Ubuntu (whether to choose sda1, sda2, sdb1, sdb2...). The interface is different from Windows installation.
you should have free space, for your Ubuntu partition, formed and ready before you start the Ubuntu installation. It is for the best, and you can easily do it from Windows Disk Management.

**Before installing Ubuntu you should really try it first**. It is important to know whether Ubuntu's current kernel supports all of your hardware.

Take a look to this [Link](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html)

Comment: My question was for presenting the solution I used, I've seen a number of related posts which get closed / referred back to answers regarding options within the Ubuntu installer. This is a solution that involves adjusting BIOS settings pre and post install.

Comment: Also wanted to add Ubuntu has great support for the Acer Aspire V3-575T, was watching netflix on a wireless connection, in minutes.

Comment: Ok!  Good to know!

Answer (score -1):

Instructions for an **Acer Travelmate P249 Series** below:

- Reboot the computer
- Enter the BIOS with <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Use the arrow keys to navigate to the `BOOT` screen
- Select <kbd>Secure Boot</kbd> and change value to `disable`
- Select <kbd>Boot priority order</kbd> and move `USB`, `HDD`, `DVD`, etc. to the top
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit
- Proceed with the installation type of choice.
- After the Windows installation has completed, and is prompting you to restart:

  - Remove the USB drive
  - On reboot, Access the BIOS again with 

    F2

    On the BIOS page Select <kbd>UEFI file as trusted</kbd>

    Navigate to:

    - HDD0
    - EFI
    - Ubuntu
    - select `SHIMX64.EFI` (Enter OS Name as your wish)

    Navigate to the BOOT tab:

    - Select <kbd>Secure boot</kbd>
    - change value to `Enabled`
    - F10 to save and exit.
- Install Ubuntu complete and reboot the computer.

Every time you boot the computer press F12 and select the operating system you want to boot.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** I'm a bit confused by your instructions: how chan you select SHIMX64.EFI when Ubuntu ins not yet installed??  Do you need to do that after the Ubuntu installation?