# Ubuntu won't boot from HDD after clean install from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, acer

Bought a new Acer Aspire ES1-572 with windows 10 pre installed; made a ubuntu 16.04 usb flashdrive and installed ubuntu after a trial next to windows. Worked beautifully. Since I really want to get rid off Bill Gates, after a few days of flawless working, decided to reinstall ubuntu from the fdd and wipe disk in the process. From then on, the laptop will not start up without the fdd as booting device. When on its own, it says: no boot device found. Funny, after installation it said: install succesfull, go on trying ubuntu, or restart from harddrive. Looks like there is something missing.

What do I do?

Comment: Try reinstalling ubuntu again. Usually works! By the way, you did set the boot installation to the entire hard drive, right? I think you can also set partition's flag to boot, but I'm not too sure if that would work. If I were you, I'd reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: It seems sometime this happens because of a mistake in choosing the partition for installing grub on. You can solve the problem by using [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Tried reinstalling ubuntu serveral times, but no luck. I did not try boot repair, but decided to take the new Acer back to the shop. They do boot repair and windows reinstall. Afterwards I'll partition the hdd to run ubuntu next to windows, with minimal size for Bill. Won't take chances no more. Suspect Acer protects microsoft to disencourage Linux. Pfff.

Comment: I detailed the solution for an Acer Aspire V3 here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home/886561#886561