# Acer Aspire V15 Nitro (Black Edition) - Won't boot from bootable USB stick

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, acer, aspire

stuck on this issue for 4 days, would appreciate any help!

So, I am trying to install Dual Boot of Win10 and Ubuntu18 on my Acer Aspire V15 (VN7-592G).
If I plug in the USB drive, it won't boot the Linux installation screen, always only to Windows.

I tried everything I could find online to fix it:

1. Deactivate Fast Start Up in Windows.
2. Deactivate Secure Boot in BIOS Settings.
3. Reduce Volume of C: by the half. The other half (D:) is a GPT.
4. Make Bootable Stick with RUFUS and the official Ubuntu18 ISO. I used GPT as partition scheme, the target system UEFI(without CSM), the type FAT32 and the size 8GB - as the RUFUS settings.
5. Activate F12 Menu in BIOS Settings.
6. Changing Boot Priority of USB HDD to First.
   Now I tried both ways:
   7a. Turning laptop on and pressing F12. Then selecting "Command Linpus Lite (Generic Flash Disk)" or "Linpus lite (Generic Flash Disk)"
   7b. Turning laptop on without F12 (as I changed the boot priority already).

So the weird thing is, the laptop recognizes the Flash drive in the "F12 Menu", but won't boot from it, even though I select it. It will just start Windows and show my login screen.
Also, when I plug in a Win Installer on USB (Tried Win8), it is able to boot the installation menu without issues.
(I also tried a Ubuntu14 bootable USB stick, but this didn't work neither. Even though, here it at least shows the common screen "Try Ubuntu"/ "Install Ubuntu", but then the screen stays black - won't do anything.)

Some background info:
I have the laptop for 6 days (it was second hand from Amazon Warehouse). The moment I unpacked it, the originial Win10 was so slow (with all that extra programs that I don't need from Acer), so I spent two days trying to install Ubuntu. This finally worked by following these instructions:

*"Detailed steps I used to successfully install:

- Create a boot USB with the Ubuntu image file using Rufus as detailed here:https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
- Insert USB in the forward left hand side USB connector (the USB connector on the right side of the computer will not work)
- Reboot the computer and access the BIOS with F2: Use arrow keys to navigate to BOOT screen
- Select Secure Boot and change value to disable
- On the Boot priority order move USB-HDD to the top F10 to save and
  exit
- Proceed with the installation type of choice

After the installation has completed, and is prompting you to restart:

- Remove the USB drive (on reboot)
- Access the BIOS again with F2 On the
- BIOS page Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing Navigate to: HDD0 > EFI > 'ubuntu' and select SHIMX64.EFI (Enter shimx64 as name)
- Navigate to the BOOT tab: Select Secure boot, change value to Enabled
- F10 to save and exit

I followed these exact steps, installed without errors, and am using Ubuntu on
my Acer V3 now."*

------------ [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home) (11.08.2018)

﻿Though to the fact that I need Dual Boot, I needed to have Windows installed first, so I installed Win8 (what I usually prefer over Win10). 
Installing it worked easily, but I then had issues with the drivers as Acer only provides them for Win10, and I couldn't find ones for my network and sound card, so I installed Windows 10 using the official Win10 ISO from Microsoft.

It's not the first time I am working with BIOS, OS, etc. I am usually doing that without issues on SONYs, DELLs, etc. but this Acer is driving me crazy!!

Any idea what I could have missed?

I really don't want to give up on this one, as I - given the hardware specs - got this laptop really cheap from amazon's warehouse (it was second hand, though looks as new).

Thanks a lot

PS: Laptop details:

Intel Core I7 6th Gen // 16 GB RAM // 1TB HDD //NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 960 4 GB // 4K (3840 x 2160) -> Maybe it's due to some resolution issues?

Comment: Do you see anything like a “legacy BIOS” option in the F12 menu? If so I would try that.