# Ubuntu Installation boot issues with usb installation

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, live-usb, error-handling

Hi everyone ive been trying to install ubuntu 20.04 for a few hours and once i get to the remove medium installation and press enter the installtion does some sort of boot loop but does not have ubuntu installed please would a kind soul please explain to me how to go about this issue

forgotten point NB! at the end of the installation the (first time) when you get the restart system prompt i pulled out my flash drive when i shouldnt have i think this might be cause issues.

also im trying to install this on an old laptop with 2gigs ram and one of the celeron line up cpus (dont know which cpu it is exactly as i dont think i can check in the machines current state.

My laptop [link](https://icecat.biz/en/p/acer/nx.mz8ea.006/aspire-notebooks-es1-531-c17m-35852084.html)

Comment: pls explain what you mean with boot loop and perhaps you could change the boot-device in bios/uefi

Comment: basically the laptop keeps restarting itself with some text all that I could catch was that it said reset system because the process is very quick it starts up without ubuntu installed when i installed it then has a blue box with menu buttons and some other options which i forget what are called, so i click continue boot but it still has issues as if ubuntu was never installed sorry if this is hard for readers i dont exactly know how to explain the problem

Comment: perhaps you can tell us the manufacturer and the model or serial number - what ever you can find on the laptop might be of great help - so we can figure out which buttons to press to get to bios/uefi - one of these are quite common `Esc`, `F2`, `F10`, `F12` and `Del`-- the key needs to be hit right after xou turn it on -- when `some text is shown -- here is a little hint for entering bios/uefi https://www.tomshardware.com/uk/reviews/bios-keys-to-access-your-firmware,5732.html

Comment: The laptop is 64 bit i can tell you that for sure

Comment: Alright ive gotten some more details the laptops model name is Acer Aspire ES1-531-C17M
and the laptop was manufactured in 2015/09/09
heres a linkt to my laptop [link](https://icecat.biz/en/p/acer/nx.mz8ea.006/aspire-notebooks-es1-531-c17m-35852084.html)

Comment: acer laptops are quite tricky perhaps you try this one:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home or this https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install Ubuntu on Acer Aspire ES1-533](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You db429 Your last comment helped me out and i got it working i had to use all those terminal commands from [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862946/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-acer-aspire-es1-533)