# After Installing Ubuntu on laptop and restarting, Ubuntu still not installed

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, usb-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu from a USB drive onto my laptop. I had used Rufus from another computer to burn the Ubuntu iso file on the USB. The Ubuntu version I was downloading is the lastest version (20.04.1).

Everything seemed to work fine. I got to the installation prompt where it asks you the language you prefer, the network to connect to, etc. When I got to the installation type prompt here:

[image: The prompt that I got to]

I chose the first option to erase the disk and install Ubuntu. Yet again, everything seemed to go fine and after everything installed I was prompted to unplug the installation media (which I took to be my USB) and restart. After unplugging and restarting, the computer pretended as though nothing had installed and tried to install it again, giving me the exact same prompts from the first time I was booting it up. I went to the BIOS and made sure boot priority was given to my hard drive and no luck.

I have found a question similar to mine, and the proposed solution was to take out the installation media (in my case the USB) once Ubuntu is installed. But the thing is when I take a look at the "other locations" tab in the file system Linux seems to think my hard drive is an SSD and it asks me to eject it. So I didn't want to take out my USB in case I might corrupt it.

edit: I figured it out. Apparently, once I restarted my laptop and removed the usb, going directly to the BIOS and enabling secure boot along with changing the booting priority to the USB drive (which was no longer there) worked. I now have Ubuntu on my laptop.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some only want to boot Windows and we have to do a work around. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred thanks but I was able to figure it out, I don't think my computer "only wants to boot Windows" but it is interesting that some systems do that.

Comment: Hey @peter! I'm glad that you figured it out. I request you to answer your own question if you can. It'll be helpful for the community.

Comment: Ok @peter. Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong. So everything I had done in my original answer was correct, but once I was prompted with something like "Please take out the installation media and press enter", and once I did both of those things, I went directly to the BIOS and enabled secure boot. I then changed the boot order so that my hard drive was at the top of the list. If the secure boot option isn't able to be highlighted, then one would have to go to the tab in BIOS where it lets you set passwords for the secure boot. Once a password is made, press f10 to save everything and Ubuntu was working. I was using an Acer laptop for the installation process and the information I got for this workaround comes from [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home).